# What is the difference between drin and darin?

Tags: standard-german

What is the difference between drin and darin?

I often hear people saying these two words, but I am not sure about situations on how to use them.

Answer (score 4):

"Drin" is a colloquial short form of two different words,  either

> darin

or

> drinnen

So one can use "drin" in colloquial speech short for "darin", but not the other way: when "translating" colloquial speech in a formal form, one has to decide if *drin* is used as short form of *darin* or *drinnen*.

Examples:
Die Kinder spielen lieber **drin**. -> Die Kinder spielen lieber **drinnen**.
Ich habe **drin** nichts gefunden. -> Ich habe **darin** nichts gefunden.

Comment: I'm not sure if its a colloquial form of "drinnen" too. The "e" is nearly not hearable in colloquial speech, but shortening it to "drin" sounds wrong for me.

Comment: @Iris Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/drin) unterstützt die Sichtweise.

Comment: es gibt auch Google Treffer für "drin spielen", es gibt also Leute, die das sagen. Für mich hört es sich trotzdem seltsam an.

Comment: @Iris. I guess, there is some flexibility on how people spell it out on the internet. I agree with your observation that it is common to pronounce it  "drin|n" with a silent _e_. On the other hand, I believe many non-native speakers have trouble hearing such details anyway. As the question was referring to spoken language, I would think it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

'drin' is a contraction of the word 'darin'. source: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drin

As such, it is colloquial to use 'drin', but as you noticed both forms are common in daily conversation.  As a beginner, I wouldn't worry too much about it.

In official writing / letters, and public speeches, one should use only the formal 'darin', though.